# Azure AD Single sign on with OpenSAML2 API

Tags: java, azure, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

We are using **OpenSAML2 API** in our **Service Provider**. We need to integrate with Azure AD single sign-on (**Identity Provider**). Please guide us, how can we integrate this.

Thanks

Comment: Check this, if it answers you question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/184403/azure-ad-single-sign-on-with-opensaml2-api.html

Comment: Understood. But please explain it more for easy understanding.